# Getting a video error after writing Ubuntu Mate to a SD card

Tags: hdmi, display, ubuntu

I have written an Ubuntu Mate image file to an SD card using win32disk manager. When I insert it into the Raspberry Pi, it keeps displaying the following message on the monitor:

> Digital Input - Cannot display this video mode

I am using a HDMI Cable and a HDMI to VGI converter cable.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the monitor does not support whatever mode the Pi has selected. Why? It should select one from the advertised modes. You could try un-commenting `#hdmi_safe=1` in `config.txt` or setting a supported mode.

Comment: How can i do that when i am getting blank display.

Comment: I stopped using converter cable and used HDMI cable with HDMI display. Now I am getting the display.

Comment: @pradeep You can (and normally do) set the configuration by editing the boot partition on any computer, usually the one you set up the SD card on.

Comment: how to do that.? Could you please explain in brief.. That would help me a lot.

Comment: @pradeep read https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md The other Documentation is essential reading.